# Is there any way to get value from specified position From List variable Automation Anywhere?

Tags: list, rpa, automationanywhere

I want to get a value from particular location from list variable. Right now what i see is it only uses loop to iterate over in Automation anywhere.

SO is there any way to get value from a specified location?

Comment: Short answer is no. You would need to use Arrays instead. For greater flexibility I recommend XML.

Answer (score 0):

For now, this is your only option to get a value from a specific location/index on a list.
I hope that Automation Anywhere includes a command/option to do that in the next release(s).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you'll have to loop over the list, and have a counter variable to get the item on the position you want.

After that you exit the loop. Not very efficient, but I just had to do it today :(

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the list elements, you can modify and delete them directly much easier and quicker in G1ANT software, even without executing the loop.

Here is the sample code:

```
♥list = Adam❚Eva❚John❚Mary
♥list⟦1⟧ = Peter
dialog ♥list
♥list⟦⟧ = 200
♥list⟦5⟧ = ♥list⟦5⟧+10
dialog ♥list
```

Enjoy!